# Unity build crashes (API level 31 and above)

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, crash, admob

My app was working perfectly fine unitl I had to upgrade the API Target level to 31 or above for Google play store publishing, but when I run the app it crashes upon startup and in the **firebase crashlytics** it shows this error:

> Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
>
> Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g.

Im using:

1. Firebase SDK (crashlytics & analytics)
2. Google admob SDK

Comment: So...did you specify `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` or `FLAG_MUTABLE` as suggested?

Comment: @MickyD Im not exactly sure how to do that in unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was finally solved by updating the google admob unity SDK & the firebase unity SDK.